# Dynamic List Creation based on given object type in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, types

I am fairly certain this is possible, and I am thinking it is easy and I just don't know the right way to ask the question in Google.  What I want to do is take pass a `type` into a method and return back a list of objects of that type.  something like this:

```
public List<T> GetComponentsOfType(Type thisType)
{
    return Components.OfType<thisType>().ToList();
}
```

which of course doesn't compile because I don't know what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to pass in the type parameter so you can get the typed list:

```
public List<T> GetComponentsOfType<T>()
{
    return Components.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was so close. =)  -- do you know what the technical terms are in here, i.e. what I could have searched for in Google to find this answer?

Comment: The first effective one I found was `method pass in type return c#`. First but is decent.